# git commit automatically update latest content?

Tags: git

I knew `git add` command will make files in "staged" state.
If I change the content of staged files, **I should `git add` them again to update content in index.**

That concept is from book. But subversion don't need to do that.
So I just `git commit` them for convinence.

I found the content changed after `git add` were committed normally.
So, that means `git commit` update changed content in index automatically even without `git add` ?

And why book say we shoud `git add` again to update changed content in staged files ?

Answer (score 2):

There's two possibilities.

You ran `git commit -a` which will automatically stage modified files before commit.

You committed *part* of a modification to a file. To demonstrate: modify a file in 1 place, `git add` it. Then modify the file again in a different place, when you run `git status` you will see the same file listed in both the "staged" area and the "unstaged" area. Then if you run `git diff --cached` you can see the staged changes that will be committed when `git commit` is executed. If you run `git diff` you can see the unstaged changes that will not be committed.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  
In fact, I don't add -a option when commit my 2nd changed objects.I know your answer, but why should I `git add` them AGAIN? I can just commit them into object store without caring about anything changed after 1st `git add`.  
So, my question is: **WHY SHOULD I `git add` AGAIN?**    :)

Comment: If you don't `git add` the second set of changes, they won't be committed. If you don't care about those changes, then you don't need to commit them in the first place.

Comment: Sorry about my missing look, ctcherry.I know your point now.  
Because my **staged content(tracked files) is in my working directory.**, I can commit them directly without `git add` them repeatly, git always `git add` last changes in my working directory before actual commit. But any modification in other place wouldn't commit until they are `git add`, right?